# How to ReSize Image with Good Quality in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create a Photos Library as existing photo library in iPhone. I add image in scrollviewer which is chosen from Photo library. Before add image i resize the selected image and set it to ImageView Control.But when i compare to added image quality with iPhone Photo library image quality, my control image is not good. How to bring the quality and withou memory overflow issue.

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    // Create a bitmap context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ran into this issue also. I think you're using an iPhone 4 with Retina Display. Even if you're not, you should account for it. Instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`, use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` and use the `scale` property of `UIScreen` for the third argument. All iOS devices have the scale property, on iPhone 4 it's set to 2.0; on the rest, as I write this, it's set to 1.0.

So your code, with those changes, becomes

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    // Create a bitmap context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Comment: Rather than using `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` you can just use `image.scale`.

Comment: I read many articles and this simple solution actually works pretty well without loosing too much quality going from 2K+ down to 100px.  Just adding `...WithOptions()` did the trick.

Comment: I find it interesting that after trying many complex solutions the 5 liner method was the one that works the best and has the best quality.

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution from ageektrapped, for PNG's transparent images, you should set the second parameter to NO/false for

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(..., NO, ...);
```

will solve the black/white background issue