# How can I make AVCaptureSessionpresetPhoto take pictures at a lower resolution?

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I'm currently using AVCaptureSessionpresetPhoto to take my pictures and I'm adding filters to them. Problem is that the resolution is so big that I have memory warnings ringing all over the place. The picture is simply way to large to process. It crashes my app every single time. Is there anyway I can specify the resolution to shoot at?

## EDIT**

Photography apps like Instagram or the Facebook Camera app for example can do this without any problems. These applications can take pictures at high resolutions, scale them down and process them without any delay. I did a comparison check, the native iOS camera maintains a much higher quality resolution when compared to pictures taken by other applications. The extreme level of quality isn't really needed required for a mobile platform so it seems as if these images are being taken at lower resolution to allow for faster processing and quick upload times. Thus there must be a way to shoot at a lower resolution. If anyone has a solution to this problem, it would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: How about using another AVCaptureSessionPreset?

Comment: which one do you suggest @KhanhNguyen ?

Comment: For example `AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720`, just type "AVCaptureSessionPreset" and XCode should suggest you possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-size image after capture image using `AVCaptureSession` and store it's image after resizing.

You found lots of similar question in to StackOverlow i just putting some link bellow that makes help's you.

One More thing As my suggestion that using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for Displaying Images asynchronously Becouse App working smoothly. There are also some other way for example([Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) , [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html) etc) in iOS for asynchronous Tast

**Re-size Image**:-

[How to resize an image in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018617/how-to-resize-an-image-in-ios/17018706#17018706)

[UIImage resizing not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491080/uiimage-resizing-not-working-properly)

[How to ReSize Image with Good Quality in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677967/how-to-resize-image-with-good-quality-in-iphone)

[How to resize the image programmatically in objective-c in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712329/how-to-resize-the-image-programatically-in-objective-c-in-iphone)